# Что то типа md5 картинки - вычисление уникальности

Tags: php, хеширование, md5

Как лучше вычислять уникальность картинки на php

Чтоб создать папку в которую сохранять картинки с именем уникального ключа по типу md5

Потом при новой загрузке вычислять код уникальности и искать по нему в папке не была ли загружена раньше картинка

Comment: а чем собственно md5 не подходит?

Comment: MD5 не вариант. ИМХО. Одному хэшу может соответствовать множество комбинаций.
Как вариант можно использовать несколько разных хэшей и суммировать их.

Comment: @naym, вероятность коллизии в MD5 == 2^-128. Об этом стоит задумываться, если планируется что-то типа инстаграма)

Comment: [Яндекс.Картинки и дубликаты изображений](http://company.yandex.ru/technologies/duplicates/)

Comment: А вы знаете, что у любого хеша есть коллизии? Чтобы гарантированно не было коллизий, надо просто сравнивать картинки.

Answer (score 7):

Интересная тема. В простом варианте нужна ф-я «отпечатка пальца» (fingerprint), чтобы сравнить картинки. Пример: уменьшить картинку до 32x32 точек, квантизировать цвета до значений из 16. Вот и «хэш» — если у двух картинок результат такого округления совпал — вероятно, они одинаковы. Хотя их изначальные разрешения не совпадают.

Если требуется б**о**льшая разборчивость, уменьшайте до 64x64, цвета округляйте до 64, и т.п., исходя из задачи. Вопрос для размышления: считать ли одинаковыми картинки, у одной из которых присутствует еле заметный полупрозрачный мелкий watermark в углу?

В более глубоком подходе, нужно учитывать разное кадрирование, поворот картинки на произвольный угол, но в данной задаче это, вроде бы, не требуется. Близкие вопросы про реализацию [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/) на SO: [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005115/what-algorithm-could-be-used-to-identify-if-images-are-the-same-or-similar-re) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314375/i-wonder-how-reverse-image-search-services-like-tineye-com-work).